# Property 'onClick' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong...
Any help will be appreciated:

```
type Props = {
  onClick: () => void, 
  value: string
}

const CustomInput = forwardRef<Props>(({ onClick, value }, ref) => (
  <div className="react-datepicker-custom-input" onClick={onClick}>
    {value}
    <i className={classes.arrowDown}></i>
  </div>
));


error message: Property 'onClick' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }
```

export default CustomInput;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Props` generic should go as a second argument, not the first.

Example:

```js
type Props = {
  onClick: () => void, 
  value: string
}

type RefType=number
const CustomInput = forwardRef<RefType, Props>(({ onClick, value }, ref) => (
  <div className="react-datepicker-custom-input" onClick={onClick}>
    {value}
    <i className={classes.arrowDown}></i>
  </div>
));
```

First generic argument of `forwardRef` is for ref type, second - if for props accordingly

Answer (score 3):

You can type by adding it this way:

```js
type Props = {
  onClick: () => void, 
  value: string
}

const CustomInput = forwardRef<Props>(({ onClick, value }:Props, ref:any) => (
  <div className="react-datepicker-custom-input" onClick={onClick}>
    {value}
    <i className={classes.arrowDown}></i>
  </div>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
interface Props {
      children: ReactNode;
      onClick: () => void;
      value: string;
    }

const CustomInput = forwardRef(({ onClick, value }:Props) => (
  <div className="react-datepicker-custom-input" onClick={onClick}>
    {value}
    <i className={classes.arrowDown}></i>
  </div>
));
```

Comment: Or this if you are expecting an event. 

interface Props {
      children: ReactNode;
      onClick(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>): void;
      value: string;
    }

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful with some **explanation**. Explain what it does, and how it's **different / better** than existing answers.